# AssemblyLoadContext with Castle dynamic proxies and Roslyn

Tags: .net-assembly, roslyn, castle-dynamicproxy

I am generating code with Roslyn and loading it into a collectible `AssemblyLoadContext`. Then I try to generate a Castle dynamic proxy for a class from the generated assembly in the collectible load context, but get this error:

> A non-collectible assembly may not reference a collectible assembly

I guess the issue is that the load context can't be unloaded if another non-collectible assembly is referencing it.

I have tried to load `Castle.Core.dll` into the collectible load context and then invoke proxy generation via reflection and hoped this would solve the problem. But I still get the same error. I have double-checked that all castle-types comes from the plugin-assembly-path. I assumed that all assemblies loaded into the collectible load context would become collectible themselves?

Any hope I could get this to work somehow?

Comment: This GitHub issue may be relevant: [`castleproject/Core#473`: Support Collectible Dynamic Assemblies](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/issues/473). As far as I understand it, DynamicProxy simply does not yet support this scenario.

Comment: Yes, that seem to be the problem. I have turned off collectible for now but it would be sweet if Castle DP could support this in the future.